# Hang drum, what type of music is this?

Tags: drums

I was greatly impressed by the [hang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hang_%28musical_instrument%29) when I saw [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZTOKqbNYm4) street player last year. I would like to know if there are other examples in this type of music (sounds like Gypsie music but Im not good with musical genres).

What is [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRq7fH016ig&feature=related) [type](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRq7fH016ig&feature=related) [of](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48vy2-TIcbw&feature=related) [musical](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAzEpyI10HM) genre called so I can search for it.

Comment: This may get closed since it's more of a music appreciation question, but if you haven't heard of him already you should definitely check out [Dante Bucci](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNJswfXKJ3s)--he also has an album on iTunes.

Comment: As a Star Wars fan I just love the idea there is a type of music called Hang Solo :-)

Comment: The part of your question asking for recommendations doesn't really belong on a Stack Exchange site, given the subjective nature of that question.  However, I'd like to suggest editing this question to only deal with classifying the music - seems like that could be an ok question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check out:

- [Hang Playing Hedge Monkeys](http://www.hangplayinghedgemonkeys.com)
- [Manu Delago](http://www.manudelago.com/eng/home.htm)
- [Davide Swarupe](http://www.davideswarup.com/)

Here's some more:

- [Portico Quartet](http://porticoquartet.com/)
- [Dante Bucci](http://www.dantebucci.com/)
- [Wadhom](http://www.myspace.com/wadhom)
- [Matt Venuti](http://mattvenuti.com/)
- [Masood Ali Khan](http://masoodalikhan.com/)
- [Laura Inserra](http://www.laurainserra.com/en/Home.html)
- [Janet Spahr](http://www.spahrstudios.com/studios/About.html)

— From [HandPansMagazine - Hang/HandPans Music](http://www.hangdrumsandhandpans.com/p/hanghandpans-music.html#en), check it for more information and links.

Answer (score 6):

The artist you give in reference, Lior Shoov, has not one style in particular but very much a style of her own. She uses one or several hang pans, the ukulele, hand bells.  The music itself has motives directly inspired from classical music (and film music à la Yann Tiersen) as in the extract of her performance in Tarrega. Her voice and singing sometimes remind of the famous icelander singer Bjork's style.

In other performances, she sings partly improvised lyrics in Hebrew, the way she plays the hang is sometimes close to a piano, sometimes close to the effect of the jamaican steel drum (this is not surprising because of the basis of the two instruments) but in solo and with less resonance and mixing of successive notes.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not a separate musical genre, as much as just the special sound of the Hang drum (which is quite unique!). I think you will find much to like in the same style by just searching for `Hang` on YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Hang%3B&search=tag

Comment: I specially like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuYW8GegdWQ&feature=list_related&playnext=1&list=SP9D55761CAB978D87) where Dante Bucci plays on two Hang drums to get a wider specter.